# Create unique relationship based on relationship attribute

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Just like we can create a unique constraint on a "Node" attribute, can i create a unique constraint on a "Relationship" attribute. In my system every relationship has a unique "name" attribute, i want to enforce it in neo4j.

Thank you
Utpal

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no support for unique constraints on relationships in neo4j 3.0.x, and nothing in the 3.1 beta documentation. Relationships can have existence constraints (for neo4j enterprise), but no unique constraints.

The best you can do is ensure you're always using MERGE when creating your relationships and that the name attribute is present for that MERGE.